# Dart convert map list to String list

Tags: dart

Suppose I have a List like the one below:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> person = [
  {
    "id" : "01",
    "name" : "Tony"
  },
  {
    "id" : "02",
    "name" : "Stark"
  }
]
```

How to convert the above variable into String id list as follows : `["01","02"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of List.Map like this

```
List<String> newList = List<String>.from(person.map((element) {
    return element['id'];
  }));

// [01, 02]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dart's [**collection for**](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) construct:

```dart
var ids = <String>[for (var map in person) map['id']];
```

Answer (score 1):

And a little shorter solution:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> person = [
    {"id": "01", "name": "Tony"},
    {"id": "02", "name": "Stark"}
  ];

  final ids = person.map((m) => m["id"]).toList();
  print(ids); // [01, 02]
}
```